# Django SQLite3 перейти на MySQL

Tags: mysql, django, phpmyadmin, sqlite3

Есть проект(django 1.8 python 3.4), разработанный на стандартной локальной установке Django с БД Sqlite3. Сейчас переношу его на хостинг с базой на MySQL. 
Собственно вопросЫ:

- можно ли как-нибудь (при наличии пустой БД Mysql) сгенерировать
  таблицы по моим моделям (как это можно было сделать с Sqllite3 при
  помощи `python manage.py syncdb`  ) ?

  - если нет, то (на хостинге phpMyadmin ) мне придется вручную формировать все таблицы, заполнять их информацией и тп?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Django 1.8 для создания таблиц по моделям используют команду `python manage.py migrate` не `syncdb`
Таблицы создаются точно так же как на sqlite, только нужно внести изменения в переменную `DATABASES` в `settings.py` указать путь до базы данных, юзера и т.п.
[линк на документацию](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/databases/)